# Por que essa instrução SQL está incorreta?

Tags: sql

```
SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE categoria = 'Vestidos' AND cor = 'Branco' OR cor = 'Rosa'
```

Retornou 3 registros, 2 deles da categoria **Vestidos**, e 1 da categoria **Sapatos**. Por que não retornou somente da categoria **Vestidos** já que eu instrui `categoria = 'Vestidos'`?

Comment: Pode colocar o conteúdo integral da sua tabela no corpo da pergunta?

Comment: O sapato por acaso é cor = rosa, verifique se o resultado não foi vestido branco ou qualquer coisa rosa?

Comment: sim, também! todos os registros coincidem com a cor, mas a categoria não(no caso puxou Sapatos ao invés de Vestidos como eu pedi..)

Comment: Vocês acham que o OR ali é como se, eu pedisse ao SQL vestidos da cor branca ou Rosa(ai poderia ser sapato rosa)..

Answer (score 13):

O `AND` tem precedência sobre o `OR`. Então seu critério é entendido assim:

```
(categoria = 'Vestidos' AND cor = 'Branco') OR cor = 'Rosa'
```

Você precisa colocar os parênteses no local adequado para conseguir o resultado desejado.

Comment: obg pela ajuda!

Answer (score 6):

Em alternativa as outras respostas, você pode também utilizar o operador de comparação [IN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html) para verificar se o valor pretendido está dentre um conjunto de valores, exemplo:

```
SELECT * 
FROM produtos 
WHERE categoria = 'Vestido' AND cor IN ('branco','rosa');
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE categoria = 'Vestidos' AND (cor = 'Branco' OR cor = 'Rosa')
```

Comment: obg pela sugestão!

Answer (score 5):

Entenda a sua consulta como sendo a seguinte (explicando do modo conversa de bar):
Você quer saber se existe produtos da categoria 'Vestidos' e da cor 'Branco' e caso não seja isso (OR) que seja da cor 'Rosa', ou seja, ele esquece as duas condições anteriores  e passa a interpretar somente a última, ou se houver resultados para as duas condições ele retorna.

Sendo assim se a condição cor = 'Rosa' faz parte da condição categoria = 'Vestidos', sua consulta deverá associar os "OR's" com parenteses, sendo:

```
SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE categoria = 'Vestidos' AND (cor = 'Branco' OR cor = 'Rosa')
```

A forma correta

Comment: Ah perfeito.. meu insconciente já estava a interpretar dessa maneira, mas esqueci que o código também precisa saber o que eu quero, kkk! obrigado!!

Comment: Sua mulher diz: "Amor, vá ao supermercado e compre 6 ovos. Se tiver tomate, compre 9." Voce chega trazendo o que?